# clear textbox when click commandbutton with checkbox clicked-VBA

Tags: vba

I'm wondering how to do clear textboxes when click commandbutton1  with checkbox1 clicked, because it seems to be impossible to do like this

[when clicking the commandbutton and the checkbox is checked, i want to clean those textboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4MIF.png)

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: it really depends if your checkbox is embed within a frame. If yes, you have to manipulate the frame's value. Add details to your question

Comment: there's a screenshot, is it still not enough?

Comment: The Answer is:  privat sub CommandButton1_Click()                                                    
   If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        ComboBox1 = ""
        TextBox1 = ""
        TextBox2 = ""
        TextBox3 = ""
    End If     end sub

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If CheckBox1 Then
        TextBox1.Value = ""
    End If

End Sub
```